# How to draw half - filled nodes in a networkx graph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I am drawing a graph using the NetworkX library where I want semi-circular nodes.

The `node_shape` attribute in `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` refers to the `matplotlib.scatter` marker specifications. But, there is no option of a half-filled circle. Moreover matplotlib.lines has the attribute `fillStyles`, but I am confused about how I can implement in the code.

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                           node_list = nodes.keys(),
                           node_size = [n for n in nodes.values()],
                           node_color = '#78CCF0',
                           node_shape = '.',
                           alpha = 0.77)
```

Here's a quick look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8gRB.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.dodecahedral_graph()
nodes=nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos=nx.spring_layout(G),
                             node_shape=matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle(marker='o', 
                                                                       fillstyle='top'))
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely solved the problem. Although I was wondering if we could custom fill the nodes? i.e. `fillstyle =  60% of the node`?